# How to configure this .pl file

Tags: oracle, perl

I'm trying to import or install [MusicBrainz' database](https://github.com/elliotchance/mbzdb) and I'm following [this](https://github.com/elliotchance/mbzdb/wiki/Installation) instruction.

My OS is Windows so I'm following Windows instruction. I've done up to number 4, but when I opened to configure settings.pl file([link](https://github.com/elliotchance/mbzdb/blob/master/settings.pl)) I couldn't understand what that file wants me to configure.

I think the lines looking like this

```
$g_schema_url   = "$schema_base/admin/sql/CreateTables.sql";
```

is the part I need to change for the file to work, but I don't think I understand these lines.

I googled and found out that .pl files are the files written in a language called Perl. But I didn't download or install the language because the instruction didn't require me to. Should I? I really am a beginner so even I sound stupid I hope you can understand.

I'm working on Oracle 11.

Comment: Seems like mzdb works only on MySQL or PostgreSQL. You're out of luck on Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used MBZDB before, but I looked through the settings.pl and I don't believe for a standard install you should need to change anything. You should be able to move on to step 6.

Edit: I was incorrect: I failed to notice you are using an Oracle database. As a commenter posted, it looks like it will work best with MySQL. If you install that, though, you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you. So if I install MySQL, I can import the database and use it?

Comment: I'm not experienced in SQL, but that should work. You may have to configure something in the file, but it should give you a descriptive error message to post back here. And by the way, you did install Perl. That was step 1.